# How would I ease into a transportation to another world?

Tags: fantasy

I'm writing my own fantasy book.  In it, the characters get transported to another world. How would I go about doing that? I don't want it to be a sudden boom, you're there, and I don't want a dream world. How would I ease into the transportation?

Comment: How do your favourite relevant books do it?

Comment: What is the context of your character transitioning to another world? Is there a journey, or is it spontaneous? Is there a doorway, or does someone simply vanish? Is the character conscious when it happens (like Conrad in The Cross-Time Engineer, who falls asleep and wakes up in the past)? Does the character agree to travel, or is it involuntary? Is it pseudo-scientific, or completely mystical? Is the person coming from a modern world to a fantasy one?

Answer (score 3):

In a plot relevant manner.

For instance, if the characters are needed to face some evil that managed to immunize itself from any character from that world, a wizard might come and persuade them to come.

Or if the war in that world is damaging the fabric of reality, they might find that walking in a seldom used building has odd effects that finally cumulate in the realization that they walked into another world.

Or if they just are to have fun adventures, perhaps they find a hidden carousel and get on the horses only to find them galloping away.

Comment: I would call this *theme relevant*, but agree +1…. *Plot relevant* might be more like… well… Chekov's carousel or Checkov's abandoned building – a thing that becomes integral to the plot by the end.

Comment: The means to getting to the place are integral to the plot.  This is why whether it harmonizes with the rest is important.